linux-headers > 5.15.0.113 incompatible with virtualbox 6
After seeing Virtualbox fail to work with linux-headers versions 5.15.0.116 and 5.15.0.117, I'd like to know to whom to report this issue. I have kept 5.15.0.113 in my /boot dir because it is the latest version I can get working with Virtualbox. But I would like to not be stuck with an older kernel forever.
Virtualbox version is 6.1.50.
(vboxdrv is an important tag for this post.)

Your details are unclear; you mention an older kernel used by multiple OSes & importantly releases so we don't know what you're running (esp. release).  If your issue is in virtualbox you need to file a bug report against Oracle's virtualbox. If the issue is with the kernel change; you need file against the kernel using Ubuntu's bug reporting tools.  Firstly I'd suggest reading the actual output from a command for clues; as what you've mentioned is unclear; we don't even know your product/release.  If your heading is correct file on Oracle's bug tracking site (ie. against virtualbox).

Don't forget what Oracle have said in regards their virtualbox software, especially if a user doesn't provide their VM with sufficient resources their product can misbehave which is (as they described) a user-behavior problem they cannot fix.  Explore your own settings first to ensure you've not created the problem.

VMs working fine with 5.15.0-117 here because I'm using VB 7. Consider upgrading.

Organic Marble: Thanks. Your comment prompted me to go looking for info to upgrade Virtualbox beyond what was in the basic repo.

This is caused by a regression-update / bug with the kernel of branch 5.15; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.15/+bug/2073267 .

The solution was to take steps to get Virtualbox upgraded, such as described here: https://linuxcapable.com/install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-linux/
(In the end, the question was really about Virtualbox not working with the latest headers, and upgrading Virtualbox is the logical answer.)

Glad it helped. I strongly prefer using sw from the basic repos, but VB is one of the few examples where it pays to always have the latest.
